# Recommend a jQuery responsive carousel / slider

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm searching for a ready jQuery plugin (free or payed), that would allow me to create "responsive carousel" with touch support.

The way it should work is to show current image in middle of a site (defined width and height of image, fixed for all images, image centered vertically, height of carousel/slider doesnt change with browser width), and partly or fully visible next image on right, previous on left.
When browser is getting bigger, more and more of those "cut out" images would be seen, if browser is big enought, 3 photos would be seen fully, and next one will be cuted on right and previous on left.
Images would look like a filmstrip, with one image in middle, and as much other images visible on left and right, as browser window allows.

This image shows how this carousel should behave in various browser widths... Darkest boxes are photos aligned horizontally, lighter boxes outside of them shows diffrent browser window heights:
[image]

For those who have problems with visualing what I'm talking about, next screens show how it should look width browser windows width 1920px, 1800px 1600px and 1400px. Those are crops from entire site fullfilling entire width of a browser.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: i hate it when a question with more than 10 upvotes (obviously useful for some of us) is closed as off-topic >_<

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i was searching for something quite similar the last few days. my favorites so far

**Royal Slider**

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/visible-nearby/

this one got everything. touch support, highly customizable, responsive layout..you should be running in no time. price tag would be 12$.

**carouFredSel**

also quite powerful, touch is supported, but not as carefree and elegant as the royal slider does, but then again, its free..they have a really nice showcase page with various carousels based on their plugin..

this one might be of some interest..
http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/

Comment: It seems that RoyalSlider might me it. And as far as I was thinking about paying someone to write it, I can also buy it :).

Comment: And it fits all requirements :)

Comment: hi marcin..yep, royalslider seems to be quite top-notch and you will have customer support, if you run into problems..i found another one, which looks also very promising..http://iosscripts.com/iosslider ..runs terrible smooth on touch..i have to look into it today

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

- bxSlider : http://bxslider.com/
- FlexSlider : http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: Yeah these both look pretty cool!

Comment: +1 bxslider code is really good

Answer (score 1):

I would use this one. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/ it uses css3 animations and because it's pure css you can use @media queries to change the applied css on the slider as the screen size changes.

You can see more on media queries by looking at this boilerplate http://www.getskeleton.com/

Comment: This slider is quite a nice, but it doesn't support "film strip" look ootb, and recoding it is over my coding abilities :(

Comment: what do you mean by film strip? Do you want it to slide left to right or right to left or fade in and out?

Comment: Look at an image in my post. Dark rectangles aligned horizontally represensts photos. There is current one in center (horizontally centered), and as many on left and right as can fit in browser window. If one doesn't fit it's cut by browser window. You swipe to move one photo to left or to right.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently searched for something similar myself and found the following article: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html

looking over the examples provided in the article and on their websites and comparing them with your requirements, I think http://codecanyon.net/item/icarousel/full_screen_preview/2527180 or http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel would suite you best. The first one would require you to buy it thou.

You should take a look over the first article. It is possible that I've overlooked something or you find something even better suited ...

Answer (score 1):

Wowslider can be useful in that case.. Check once at 
http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-carousel-mac-stack-demo.html

A similar solution is also available at
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/#quickdemo

Comment: WowSlider has heaps of cool effects, really nice!  Although costs $69 for commercial use.

Answer (score 0):

**Swipe** looks pretty decent and is responsive.  It's also very smooth and supports swiping on mobiles/tablets.

http://swipejs.com/

Perhaps not quite as full-featured as Royal Slider, but it's free.